# How can I serve static pages alongside WP 3.0 multi-site?

Tags: wordpress

I've got 20+ sites on a WP 3.x install. One of them has engaged a 3rd party SEO firm that is generating static pages they want to serve under their domain.

For example, domain.com/home is a WP page, but domain.com/seo is an html page created by this 3rd party.

The client wants FTP access for the 3rd party to be able to manage these static files. They won't work through WP.

Ultimately I need to be able to do this for all sites.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the redirection plugin.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/

It allows you to specify easily subfolders which wordpress will pass through.  I have not tried it on a multi-site installation,  but as it stores everything the in DB I can not think of a reason it won't work.

You can then simply set up a FTP login for the SEO to go direct to the subfolder.